# Find a substring in pandas data frame and return that value by using for/df.iterrows

Tags: pandas, loops

I have a pandas data frame that looks like that

```
data = {'First Column Name':  ['AAA', 'BBB'],
        'Second Column Name': ['CCC', 'recat'],
        }

df = pd.DataFrame (data, columns = ['First Column Name','Second Column Name'])

print (df)


  First Column Name Second Column Name
0               AAA                CCC
1               BBB              rscat
```

I want to get the value and the index that contains the string 'rs' and store them in a dictionary

Desired output

```
rscat: 1
```

Owing to the real data frame is massive I have discover in previous code that by using for loop and iterrrow is the most efficient way to itinerate my data frame.

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
```

However I do not know how get the value and its index. Of course if more than one rs found, all values with rd and their index must be save no only the first found. It could be possible that some 'rs' would be not always at the beginning of the value such as 12grsh2h3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame ({
        'First Column Name':  ['cetrem', 'BBB'],
        'Second Column Name': ['CCC', 'recat'],
        'Third Column Name' : ['abc', 'def']
    })

>>> print(df)
  First Column Name Second Column Name Third Column Name
0            cetrem                CCC               abc
1               BBB              recat               def

>>> s = df[df.apply(lambda x:x.str.contains("re"))].dropna(how='all').dropna(axis=1, how='all')
>>> ind = s.index.to_list()
>>> vals = list(s.stack().values)
>>> d = dict(zip(ind, vals))
>>> print(d)
{0: 'cetrem', 1: 'recat'}
```